# Order of events in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I was testing the order of events in ui-router, I was expecting that `$stateChangeSuccess` would be after `$viewContentLoaded` but it was not, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Order of events for ui-router]

If I am loading the views remotely, via templateUrl property, it may take sometime for it to load (depending on the network connection). I was showing my loading indicator by watching stateChangeSuccess/Error event and I don't want the loading indicator to stop prematurely when the view is not loaded yet. I guess I would watch `$viewContentLoaded` event but I want to be consistent with my watches (stateChangeStart/Success) etc. I am wondering if stateChangeSuccess actually waits until after view content loads?

Comment: if the logging disproves your expectations, why wouldn't you just accept what it is telling you?

Comment: It seemed counterintuitive that $stateChangeSuccess would trigger before $viewContentLoaded. For example, what if view content does not load? Why state change would be a success? I wanted to know what I am missing.

Comment: not to me, suppose you need to react to it in controllers?

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe it needs a new event called $viewContentDownloaded (useful if it is from url of course) before $stateChangeSuccess so I would know that it is downloaded safely. If view download fails, state change would not be considered successful. I mean if ui-router waits until resolves are resolved, why wouldn't it wait until the template is downloaded? Maybe angular is not providing that info or there is not an easy way to listen/watch for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always loads in that order.

I just tested it by putting a delay in a resolve and in templateProvider (to delay view) and in both cases order of events were same.

Also, when I delayed the view load in templateProvider, $stateChangeSuccess did not fire until the view is loaded (there was nothing in resolves to delay it). So, $stateChangeSuccess does not fire before the view is loaded.